# Reason for virtual servers going down

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp-proliant

I understand that the following question will not give nearly enough detail regarding our setup for a complete answer. But I'm hoping to get some useful comments and hints. We are a company of about 30 people and our setup includes an EMC SAN and a two physical servers running vmware.

Twice (three days apart) some or all of the virtual servers went down and the individual desktops lost their connection to the internet (apparently due to the local DNS server going down). Our 3rd party IT consultants gave the explanation below. I'm the IT Manager, but not a VM expert and have to rely on the 3rd party. What I would like to know is whether the following explanation makes sense. (There are a few problems with the explanation that I see, but I would like to know experts' opinions.)

Many thanks in advance!

> The issue was caused by an interruption of network traffic between one of the host servers and the SAN (location of the VM files). A cable was replaced and another network port is now in operation on the affected server which should remediate the issue for now. However, currently the VMware environment is using two servers, one newer and one older, this configuration causes a problem in the vmware the environment.
>   The vmware environment cannot effectively move machines between the two servers in the event of a problem because the CPU families are too far apart. Ultimately if both servers had the same family of CPU’s or if they were even one family apart, the server that maintained connection with the SAN would have picked up the slack and the environment would not have gone down.
>
> The newer server is an HP Proliant DL 380 G9 and the old server an HP Proliant DL 360 G7. The G7 is currently considered by HP (as a retired server) on extended support since April of 2013 with official End of life in April of 2018. On the other hand the G9 server was first released in 2014 so as you can see there is a big gap between the servers.
>
> I would recommend the purchase of  G9 server to replace the outdated G7 so that we can maintain stability of the environment

Comment: This is the exact sceanrio that VMware EVC mode is intended to address. Not knowing anything about HP servers it's impossible for me to say whether or not the 3rd party was giving you accurate information regarding these two hosts or not. You also didn't specify which version of ESXi you're running on these hosts, which also has some bearing on the answer. - https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1005764

Comment: So were they giving you accurate information? Probably/Possibly.

Comment: It's _plausible_, but... EVC ought to work between those generations of servers.